# Как создать массив всех label'ов, которые уже лежат на форме?

Tags: c#, wpf, label

На форме лежат лейблы и мне хотелось бы их как-нибудь проиндексировать,чтобы работать с ними посредством их индексов. Для этого я решил создать массив лейблов, но не знаю как правильно это сделать

Comment: обращаться по индексу с целью только изменить содержимое?

Comment: да, например, label[1].Content = "text";

Comment: mvvm используете?

Comment: не использую...

Comment: Тогда используйте. При этом подобных желаний не будет возникать вовсе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ну как вариант засунуть их в `ListBox` и обращаться через `Items`

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>()
{
    new Label {Content = "one" },
    new Label {Content = "two" }
};


lstBox.ItemsSource = labels;
((Label)lstBox.Items[1]).Content = "one";
```

**UDP**: добавить существующие

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>() { lb1, lb2, lb3 };

labels[2].Content = "bla-bla";
```

Comment: а где в этом коде я добавляю в лист уже существующие лэйблы,например с названиями lbl1, lbl2, lbl3?

Comment: @РустемВалеев, а, у вас они не упорядоченные получаются? то есть лежат не в одном списке на форме?

Comment: нет, упорядоченности нет

Comment: @РустемВалеев, тогда зачем обращаться по индексу? Так легко запутаться.  Как вариант обновлю ответ как добавить существующие

Comment: @РустемВалеев, обновил

Comment: Ошибка 1 Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Prject.MainWindow.lb1" требуется ссылка на объект

Comment: @РустемВалеев, у меня все работает, покажите вашу разметку в xaml и что вы хотите сделать в коде. (обновите вопрос)

Comment: <Label x:Name="lb1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6"></Label>
       и т. д.
При нажатии на кнопку меняется содержимое лэйбла

Comment: проблема решена

Comment: @РустемВалеев, хорошо. Постарайтесь изучить как создавать проекты с использованием mvvm

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: @РустемВалеев пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Можно собирать элементы, которые лежат на форме. К примеру, напишем метод, который ищет элементы на форме и возвращает нам список этих объектов, следующим образом:

```
public static List<T> FindChilds<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (parent == null)
        return null;

    List<T> foundChilds = new List<T>();
    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

    for (int index = 0; index < childrenCount; index++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, index);
        T childType = child as T;
        if (childType == null)
        {
            var result = FindChilds<T>(child);
            if (result.Any())
            {
                foundChilds.AddRange(result);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foundChilds.Add((T)child);
        }
    }
    return foundChilds;
}
```

А в нужном нам месте, вызываем наш метод и получаем список объектов по типу, вот так:

```
var labels = FindChilds<Label>(Application.Current.MainWindow);
```

> [Класс VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx) - предоставляет вспомогательные методы для
>   выполнения типичных задач, связанных с узлами в визуальном дереве.

---

Проверил на кнопках (`Button`), закинул на форму две кнопки (*Import Images* и *Button*) и вызвал метод, вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ещё возможно устроить цикл `foreach` для всех контролов на форме, затем каждый контрол проверять по типу и если тип подходит - добавлять в массив.