# Как сделать массив кнопок глобальной переменной?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

У меня есть массив кнопок с которыми я работаю через некоторые методы, и в каждом из них приходится пересоздавать(Button[,] buttons = new Button[,]  {...}) этот массив чтобы работать с ним. Можно ли этот массив сделать глобальной переменной?

Answer (score 5):

1. Правильный способ: не использовать глобальных переменных.
2. Плохой способ: объявить в каком-то одном классе, (который будет виден из нужных методов) статическую переменную (или свойство) нужного типа.

Comment: +1 за первый способ. Глобальные переменные — зло!

Answer (score 3):

Как говорилось ранее, глобальные переменные - это плохо. Но все зависит от того, насколько они глобальны, а именно - какова область видимости.

К примеру, у нас есть класс формы, внутри которого есть методы, в которых необходим массив кнопок, к которому мы периодически обращаемся, будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Button[,] buttons; // может быть Button[]?

    public MainWindow()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         buttons = new Button[,] {...} // тут мы инициализируем наш массив (к примеру) 
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // внутри метода мы как-то работаем с нашим массивом кнопок
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // внутри метода мы как-то работаем с нашим массивом кнопок
    }
}
```

Привел примитивный пример, где `buttons` видимо в пределах `MainWindow`. В таком виде это все же выглядит не так страшно, как могло бы быть на самом деле. Поэтому в Вашем случае *необходимо выбрать оптимальную область видимости переменной*.

А еще, в принципе можно написать метод, который будет возвращать вам список кнопок лежащих на определенном компоненте, вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576432/189339). Конечно, возможно это не подойдет для решения Вашей задачи, но осмелюсь предложить Вам в качестве примера для ознакомления.

P.S.: `Button[,]` - это двумерный массив (взято из Вашего вопроса), возможно имеет смысл использовать одномерный массив `Button[]`?